# Await on observable subscription Angelar2

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, angular-http

In my Angular2 application, i use the canActivate to allow access to pages. 
A part of this is to check with the server that the token has not been tampered with, so before i can decide weather a user can be granted access, i need to call my api. 
This means subscribing to an Observable and awaiting an answer.

I need to return true or false, but since i make an asyns call, i cannot return based on my response. 
I realize i cannot await since it is single threaded, but i need to somehow block until i have an answer back from the api.
my canActivate looks as follows:

```
canActivate() {
   this.guardClient.checkToken("token")
  .subscribe(response => {
    let responseText = response.text().replace(/"/g, '');
    if ( responseText === 'Ok')
    {
      return true;
    }
    if(responseText === 'denied') {

      this.router.navigate(['login']); // redirecting to login
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the CanActivate interface in angular 2 I see the following:

```
export interface CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:     RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

As you can see, you can just return an Observable as well, and not just a boolean. 
This means your code could be rewritten something like this.

```
canActivate() {
 return this.guardClient.checkToken("token")
   .map(response => {
     let responseText = response.text().replace(/"/g, '');
     if ( responseText === '  Ok')
      {
       return true;
      }
     if(responseText === 'denied') {
        this.router.navigate(['login']); // redirecting to login
        return false;
   }
 });
}
```

This will make Angular wait for the observable to resolve before deciding if the route can be shown or not. 
Notice that this method should be pretty fast to avoid slow loads.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! :)